# Youtube video background scaling - squarespace

Tags: html, css, iframe

Is there a page header code injection for squarespace that will allow me to scale a video to fit the background whilst having the navigation functional as well?

I'm currently using this code:

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 50; width: 100%; height: 100%">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uOTukSIEW3k?rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&loop=1&playlist=uOTukSIEW3k"> 
</iframe> 
</div>
```

however this doesn't fit the screen fully.

Sorry if the explanation is poor, very very new to this!

Thanks,

Comment: post the URL so we can see and check that

Comment: its been updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reset the body margin

CSS

```
body 
{  
   margin: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wupumapuse/edit?html,css,output)

[DEMO FULLSCREEN](http://output.jsbin.com/wupumapuse)